# Dropbox for business API, how do I link my team with my app?

Tags: ios, oauth, dropbox

I've managed to set up this with a 'normal' account with the Dropbox API. To get 'linked' with a normal account I simply logged in, but to set one up for a team is proving slightly more problematic.

The dropbox website says:

*Linking to a team
Developers will need to direct a Dropbox for Business team administrator through the standard OAuth 2.0 flow to install their application on a Dropbox for Business team. The OAuth response/redirect will include an additional team_id field that can be used to uniquely identify a team.*

So I started having a bit of a fiddle with that and came up with this (presumably i'm meant to be doing this in my browser):

https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=my_app_id&response_type=code

At which point, the website responded:

*Myappname would like to access Mycompanys's team information, plus the team's detailed activity log*

and I clicked 'Allow', to which it replies:

*'Enter this code into Myappname to finish the process.
g4LUp49asdasdD423123easdalongcodehere'*

What am I supposed to do with this return value? Could anyone tell me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code that you receive at this point is the "authorization code". Your app should exchange that for an access token via the /oauth2/token endpoint. You can find more information in the documentation at the following links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-token

There's also a blog post here that may help:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api